# JUnit avoid duplicate assertions

Tags: unit-testing, generics, junit, junit5

I am writing simple test cases for converting Entity to DTO and vice versa. The question is more about design. Is it acceptable to leave duplicates like in code below or is it better to create external method for this assert? Since I'm Java newbie can someone give me hint about hmm? any Generic method? I don't want to use and inheritance or any other abstraction for such simple Entity and its DTO because there will be much more code than just few duplicate line of code.
Here is how it looks like now:

```
@Test
void addressToAddressDTO() {
    Address address = getAddress();

    AddressDTO addressDTO = addressMapper.addressToAddressDTO(address);

    assertAll("Check if values were properly bound",
            () -> {
                assertEquals(address.getCity(), addressDTO.getCity());
                assertEquals(address.getUserDetails().getFirstName(), addressDTO.getUserDetails().getFirstName());
                assertEquals(address.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername(), addressDTO.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername());
                assertEquals(address.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail(), addressDTO.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail());
                assertEquals(address.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl(), addressDTO.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl());
            });
}

@Test
void addressDTOtoAddress() {
    AddressDTO addressDTO = getAddressDTO();

    Address address = addressMapper.addressDTOtoAddress(addressDTO);

    assertAll("Check if values were properly bound",
            () -> {
                assertEquals(addressDTO.getCity(), address.getCity());
                assertEquals(addressDTO.getUserDetails().getFirstName(), address.getUserDetails().getFirstName());
                assertEquals(addressDTO.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername(), address.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername());
                assertEquals(addressDTO.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail(), address.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail());
                assertEquals(addressDTO.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl(), address.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl());
            });
}
```

My idea was to create something more generic like:

```
private<T, S> void assertObject(T expected, S actual) {
        assertAll("Check if values were properly bound",
                () -> {
                    assertEquals(expected.getCity(), actual.getCity());
                    assertEquals(expected.getUserDetails().getFirstName(), actual.getUserDetails().getFirstName());
                    assertEquals(expected.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername(), actual.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername());
                    assertEquals(expected.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail(), actual.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail());
                    assertEquals(expected.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl(), actual.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl());
                });
    }
```

but since even they are the same objects they have nothing in common. How to achieve something hmm interchangable that Address and AddressDTO can be  both actual or expected?

**EDIT**

According to Aaron Digulla answer I've made some changes, hope it will help someone with the same doubts.If someone know any other option please post in in the comment section.

```
@Test
void addressToAddressDTO() {
    Address expected = getAddress();

    AddressDTO actual = addressMapper.addressToAddressDTO(expected);

    assertEquals(
            mergeAddressDataToString(expected),
            actual.getCity() + "," +
                    actual.getUserDetails().getFirstName() + "," +
                    actual.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername() + "," +
                    actual.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail() + "," +
                    actual.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl()

    );
}

@Test
void addressDTOtoAddress() {
    AddressDTO expected = getAddressDTO();

    Address actual = addressMapper.addressDTOtoAddress(expected);

    assertEquals(
            expected.getCity() + "," +
                    expected.getUserDetails().getFirstName() + "," +
                    expected.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername() + "," +
                    expected.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail() + "," +
                    expected.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl(),
            mergeAddressDataToString(actual)
    );
}

private String mergeAddressDataToString(Address address) {
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
    stringJoiner.add(address.getCity());
    stringJoiner.add(address.getUserDetails().getFirstName());
    stringJoiner.add(address.getUserDetails().getUser().getUsername());
    stringJoiner.add(address.getUserDetails().getContact().getEmail());
    stringJoiner.add(address.getUserDetails().getProfileImage().getImageUrl());

    return stringJoiner.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a custom `toString()` method for the object in the test or a test utility class when several tests need to share it. That way, I can check all values with a single `assertEquals()`.

I can use newlines to make the assert more readable in an IDE:

```
assertEquals(
    "city=Foo\n" + 
    "firstName=John\n" + 
    "user=doe\n" + 
    ....
    , toString(actual));
```

which also works nicely when you have to check a list of values:

```
    ...
    , list.stream().map(this::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n---\n"));
```

The big advantage here is that you get all mismatches at once. You can also tweak the `toString()` method to handle corner cases (like comparing only the number of elements for huge lists or rounding decimals).

It also makes the code easy to understand. In many cases, it also saves you the time to write the code to fill all those `expected` objects which you would need. Tests can even share expected strings when several tests should yield the same result.

When the test breaks because the output has changed, I can just select the whole string and replace it with the new output. The IDE will do the formatting for me.

Comment: I will definitely try this approach!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach, aside of the duplication, uses one antipattern: You call `assertAll`, but still put all assertions into one block.  Thus, after the first failing assertion, the block's execution will be terminated.  If instead you put each individual check in one `Executable`, in case of a failure, all checks will be performed and you will get more details about what failed and what not.  Certainly, this is no longer the problem with the string comparison approach.

Regarding the duplication, there is another idea how you could avoid it in this particular case, that is, for the tests of the two conversion functions: You could make use of the fact that a conversion back and forth between the two types is the identity function:

```
Address address = getAddress();
AddressDTO addressDTO = addressMapper.addressToAddressDTO(address);
Address actual = addressMapper.addressDTOtoAddress(addressDTO);
assertEquals(address, actual);
```

This eliminates the comparison of individual elements.  It may even be advantageous if the representation of an entity and the DTO change in a way that the attributes are no longer strictly equal, but instead only have to be convertible back and forth.

But, each test now also relies on other methods of the class under test.  Which is not a problem in general: Many tests, for example, rely on the constructor to work - which is OK if there are also tests for the constructor.  Here, however, if the test fails, there are two possible locations that are responsible, and so finding the culprit requires more analysis.

Regarding the second option you have tried, namely creating strings and comparing them: In some scenarios such an approach may be helpful, but generally I am hesitant about going from structured data to strings.  Assume you create a lot of tests using that pattern.  Later, however, you realize that in the DTO some of the attributes have to be encoded differently than in the entity (I mentioned that scenario above).  Suddenly, the conversion to strings does not work any more or becomes awkward.

With or without the strings approach: If you have more assertions where complete entity objects and DTOs have to be compared, I'd recommend writing your own assertion helper methods, like, `assertEntityMatchesDto` and `assertDtoMatchesEntity`.

One final remark: There may be reasons not to compare *all* attributes of the objects in one test: This way, the tests may not be focused enough.  Taking the example about encoding changes again: Imagine that you will have to change the representation of the email address in the DTO at some point in time.  Then, if you always look at all attributes in your tests, all your tests will fail.  If, instead, you have focused tests for individual attributes, such a change will - if done correctly - only affect tests focusing on the email attribute, but leave other tests intact.